# Is it safe to drink Iranian Aragh Sagi?

Tags: wine, health

Aragh sagi (Persian: عرق سگی, romanized: araq-e sagi, lit. doggy [metaphor for extreme] distilled [beverage]) is a type of Iranian moonshine.

This beverage contains about 50% alchol and made from grape Distillation.

My question is: **Is *Aragh Sagi* a safe drink?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it safe to drink Iranian *Aragh Sagi*?**

The short answer is **maybe**.

Personally I would be careful about drinking this if produced from the country of origin, since quality control does not exist in Iran!

> ***Aragh sagi*** is a type of Iranian moonshine. This distilled alcoholic beverage usually contains around 50% alcohol. However, since it was produced without much quality control, it may have contained more or less alcohol, at times even reaching 80%. A high-quality aragh sagi tastes similar to grappa. Some Western sources call it Persian or Iranian Vodka.
>
> Since the Iranian revolution in 1979, Alcohol is illegal in Iran. As such, homemade *Aragh sagi* in Iran is produced illegally.
>
> It is usually produced in homes from fermented raisins. Its production and possession by ordinary citizens is considered illegal in Iran (which is the case for all alcoholic beverages in Iran). Prior to 1979 revolution in Iran, this product had been produced traditionally in several cities, such as **Yazd**. Since it was outlawed after 1979, it became a black market and underground business. Today, aragh sagi is widely considered a cheap alcoholic beverage that consumers choose due to lack of other available alternative options.

Other, more controlled countries do made this and thus would be fine to drink. Again, if it comes from the country of origin be careful about drinking it.

***Aragh sagi*** is a popular Persian drink made by distilling sultana raisins. It's aged in oak barrels for 18 months, giving its unique flavour profile. Expect aromas and flavours of oak, vanilla, baking spice, and raisin. Full-bodied with a long-lasting finish. Serve alongside a rack of lamb or enjoy over ice as an after-dinner delight.